# Always visible horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jquery, css

I have a DIV who's height and width can be larger than the page. To view the information to the right, I really don't want to make the user scroll down multiple pages just so they can scroll to the right a little bit (and then have to scroll back up to find the information they were looking for).

Is there a good jQuery library that will duplicate the horizontal scroll bar of my div so it's always visible at the bottom of the page?

I do have information above my div and below is, so changing the height of the DIV isn't a route I want to head down.

Comment: It's not a possibility to make the `div`'s height never more than the `window`'s height, and use vertical scroll on the `div` as well as horizontal?

Comment: I don't know if there's a plugin that can do this specifically, but you could probably use an `absolute`ly positioned [jqueryui slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll)

Answer (score -1):

If your code contains div height > window height of the browser then to view horizontal scroll bar user will have to always scroll down the page. I was also facing the same problem but later I came to realize that user any have to scroll down to see the content of the page which is not fit into the view-port,  so I put a div having `height = window.innerHeight` using javascript and assign css property `overflow:scroll` to it now I can see horizontal scroll bar always visible on my viewport

Answer (score -2):

Add in your CSS file:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: for vertical scroll use : overflow-y: scroll;